# How to calculate intra-observer error and average difference?

Tags: error, reliability, intraclass-correlation

I am trying to assess intra-observer error in a setting where measurements where done repeatedly by a single observer. So far I'm having some conceptual and technical issues. In the dataset we have measurements of 24 variables from 40 samples done four times in different days by one researcher. The aim is to assess the reliability of the measurements of each variable. The error here is dependent on the tools used for measurements.

I am quite unsure how to approach this issue. Can intraclass correlation be used for this estimation in the case of a single observer? I would appreciate any help getting me into right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and perhaps most interpretable approach is based on mean absolute differences over all possible pairs of relevant observations.  This can be done separately for all levels (e.g., different times within the same observer, different observers).  This method is detailed in Chapter 16 of [BBR](http://hbiostat.org/doc/bbr.pdf) which will also point you to an R function that can help.

Comment: For this site, it's best to upvote answers and comments to give proper credit to those who answer you, instead of commenting thanks.